# Stubbing integration tests with Node.js, Express, SinonJS, and BusterJS

Tags: node.js, express, sinon, buster.js

I'm having issues stubbing methods when doing integration tests with a live test server.

```
describe("Group - Integration", function() {

before(function() {
    this.timeout = 1000 * 5;
    this.server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));
});

after(function() {
    this.server.close();
});

describe("group/get", function() {

    it("returns 200 and an empty body when an invalid response type is used", function(done) {
        var deferred = when.defer();

        request.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v2/username/key/not-json/group/get", done(function(error, response, body) {
            buster.assert.equals(error, null);
            buster.assert.equals(response.statusCode, 200);
            buster.assert.equals(body, "");
            deferred.resolver.resolve();
        }));

        return deferred.promise;
    });

    it("returns 401 unauthorized if invalid credentials are provided", function(done) {
        var deferred = when.defer();

        var response_body = '{ "non_field_errors": [ "Invalid API credentials." ] }';
        var stub = sinon.stub(request, 'post').yields(null, {statusCode: 400}, response_body);

        request.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v2/username/key/json/group/get", done(function(error, response, body) {
            buster.assert.equals(error, null);
            buster.assert.equals(response.statusCode, 401);
            buster.assert.equals(body, "");
            stub.restore();
            deferred.resolver.resolve();
        }));

        return deferred.promise;

    });

    // itEventually("returns 401 unauthorized if the company has been disabled", function() {
    //     expect("a").toBe("b");
    // });

});

});
```

I run the server before each "it".  However when I stub request.post, it doesn't work.  I suspect this is because I'm stubbing it after the server has started, but when I try to stub it before the server starts it doesn't work either.  Is there a good way to stub methods on a live test server?

Comment: Just an FYI, when you return a promise, you don't need to have the "done" argument in the test functions :) Buster will detect the promise and do the rest. In fact, we should probably return an error if you take "done" and return a promise. Oh well.

Comment: For your actual question.. Can you elaborate on what the "request" function is? And why are you starting an actual HTTP server when you want to stub it? Also, you're stubbing request.post but calling request.get, perhaps that is the culprit?

Comment: Good catch on request.post.  I changed that to stubbing request.get with no change.  The request function is https://github.com/mikeal/request.  I'm starting an actual HTTP server because this is an integration test.  I want to make sure that my routes work.  I need to stub request.get so that I don't hit any external APIs during the request.